# Whats the encoding of http response for image?

Tags: http

When requesting image via http like this:

```
http://s.w.org/screenshots/3.8/responsive.png
```

In response body, there is long string which represents the image before shown as image in browser. What kind of encoding is this?

For this particular request it starts with:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA6QAAAKYCAYAAABkcDW/AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAA3FpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBi
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a base64 encoded, you'll see it for example, in inline data-uri's:

http://www.phpied.com/data-urls-what-are-they-and-how-to-use/

`iVBORw0K` decodes to `?PNG`, png header